# Using a commercial SSL certificate but self-signed for images server. Will this cause security warnings in browser?

Tags: ssl, certificate, self-signed

We are planning on using a SSL certificate from GoDaddy on our primary application domain. But, we serve our images, css, and javascript files from a second domain. If we use a self-signed certificate for the domain serving the images and so forth, will it work without giving the user a warning message regarding the self-signed certificate?

Thanks in advance for any responses. BTW, please don't ask why we don't just get certificates for both. The issue is a little more complicated, but I just simplified it for the purpose of asking this question.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if I were in your shoes I'd give it a try.  You can get a free SSL cert from http://cert.startcom.org/ , and self-sign another.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will cause a security warning in your visitors' web browsers. If any of the content on a page uses an invalid certificate (even if the page itself has a valid certificate), the browser will report an error.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the response. Much appreciated.

Comment: Since your question has been answered, you should Accept it.